# How to read boolean value from json via JS

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want read returned value from this method:

```
public ActionResult ClientIsBlocked(int? clientId)
{
    if (!clientId.HasValue)
        return Json(null);

    bool isBlocked = false;

    try
      {
         isBlocked = this.clientsProvider.GetClientById(clientId.Value).IsBlocked;
       }
    catch
       {
           // logg
       }
    return Json(isBlocked);
 }
```

in java script in my view. It should be async/ajax. How to do that? 
It is my js code in view.

```
function isBlocked(id) {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("ClientIsBlocked", "CustomerManagement", new { Area = "CustomerManagement" })',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'clientId': id }),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(!data.success) {

                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: please post your Ajax call method

Comment: BTW, the `try {} catch {}` really should do something if it is the production code... Not just eating the exception.

Comment: The `data` inside your `success` should be boolean type, the `isBlocked` value. Just check this like this `console.assert(typeof(data) == "boolean")`

Comment: in your success function don't use data.suceess because data directly contains a boolean value of isBlocked property returned from server. Also return return Json(isBlocked,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); form server as you are missing JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Answer (score 1):

In your action change :

```
return Json(isBlocked);
```

to:

```
return Json(isBlocked,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

otherwise your ajax may fail throwing exception:

> > **Server Error in '/' Application.**
> >
> > This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

and in js in success callback:

```
success: function(data) {

           alert(data); // data is the bool that is returned by action
          }
```